# Getting varchar in colum value

Tags: sql, oracle11g, nested, create-table

```
CREATE TYPE CourseList1 AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(64);
/

CREATE TABLE department1 
(
    name     VARCHAR2(20),
    director VARCHAR2(20),
    office   VARCHAR2(20),
    courses1  CourseList1) 
    NESTED TABLE courses1 STORE AS courses_tab1;
    /

    BEGIN
   INSERT INTO department1
      VALUES('English', 'Lynn Saunders', 'Breakstone Hall 205',
         CourseList1('Expository Writing',
                    'Film and Literature',
                    'Modern Science Fiction',
                    'Discursive Writing',
                    'Modern English Grammar',
                    'Introduction to Shakespeare',
                    'Modern Drama',
                    'The Short Story',
                    'The American Novel'));
END;
```

When I retrieve data using

```
select * from department1
```

My output is:

English Lynn Saunders   Breakstone Hall 205 ***VARCHAR*(Expository Writing,Film and Literature,Modern Science Fiction,Discursive Writing,Modern English Grammar,Introduction to Shakespeare,Modern Drama,The Short Story,The American Novel)**

I am unaware and confused, why this **VARCHAR** is showing

Comment: Thanks juergen for edit..can you  help me on this as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just seeing the normal way SQL Developer shows a nested table. Although it shows as the nested table column name (`COURSELIST1('Expository Writing', ...)`) rather than `VARCHAR(...)`, at least in SQL Developer 4.2. If you run the query as a statement, so the the results appear in the Query Result window instead, it shows the schema name too. Different clients may choose to display the nested table in other ways.

You can [unnest your nested table](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16338_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjcol.htm#ADOBJ7264):

```
select d.name, d.director, d.office, t.column_value as course
from department1 d
cross join table(courses1) t;

NAME                 DIRECTOR             OFFICE               COURSE                                                          
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------
English              Lynn Saunders        Breakstone Hall 205  Expository Writing                                              
English              Lynn Saunders        Breakstone Hall 205  Film and Literature                                             
English              Lynn Saunders        Breakstone Hall 205  Modern Science Fiction                                          
English              Lynn Saunders        Breakstone Hall 205  Discursive Writing                                              
English              Lynn Saunders        Breakstone Hall 205  Modern English Grammar                                          
English              Lynn Saunders        Breakstone Hall 205  Introduction to Shakespeare                                     
English              Lynn Saunders        Breakstone Hall 205  Modern Drama                                                    
English              Lynn Saunders        Breakstone Hall 205  The Short Story                                                 
English              Lynn Saunders        Breakstone Hall 205  The American Novel                                              

9 rows selected.
```

If you want them as a comma-separated string you can use `listagg()` to generate that:

```
select d.name, d.director, d.office,
  listagg(t.column_value, ',') within group (order by t.column_value) as courses
from department1 d
cross join table(courses1) t
group by d.name, d.director, d.office;

NAME                 DIRECTOR             OFFICE               COURSES                                                                                                                                                                             
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
English              Lynn Saunders        Breakstone Hall 205  Discursive Writing,Expository Writing,Film and Literature,Introduction to Shakespeare,Modern Drama,Modern English Grammar,Modern Science Fiction,The American Novel,The Short Story
```

It depends what you want to do with the nested table data really.

Comment: Thanks Alex for response.

Comment: Well !! i am not able to get ouput when using listagg function,, is it due version,, i am using Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.7.0 - Production

Comment: @SriRockz - what does that mean - you don't see any results, or you see rows with values for the other columns but nothing for that expression, or truncated output, or something else?